# Unable to SSH from Mac OS to Ubuntu VM on Virtualbox

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, virtualbox, mac

I was looking for some assistance with SSH.

I have a Mac and on it, I have virtualbox installed. I have 2 VM's on it, one is a windows 10 VM and another one is Ubuntu. Both exposed to each other on host-only network.

I used PuttyGen on Windows VM and generated an ssh key, copied to clipboard, opened up authorized_keys file on my ubuntu vm and pasted it as-s. After this i was successfully able to ssh from Windows to Linux (Ubuntu).

Now, I wanted the same behaviour with my Mac, to be able to SSH to the Ubuntu VM. Unfortunately it does not work. It says permission_denied. I have tried everything possible, did a lot of scouring on the web, but to no avail:( Here are the steps which i followed - Please can someone assist. Thanks in advance!

1. I generated ssh key on my Mac - using "ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096" command which stored the keys on my id_rsa.pub file.
2. This is how the .ssh folder looks on my Mac

   ```
   drwx------   5 JK  staff   170 Nov 14 21:27 .
   drwxr-xr-x+ 36 JK  staff  1224 Nov 14 20:10 ..
   -rw-------   1 JK  staff  3243 Nov 14 21:27 id_rsa
   -rw-r--r--   1 JK  staff   756 Nov 14 21:27 id_rsa.pub
   -rw-r--r--   1 JK  staff   345 Nov 14 16:42 known_hosts
   ```
3. Now I copied the key from id_rsa.pub onto the authorized_keys file on mu ubuntu
4. This is how the Ubuntu /.ssh directory looks like

   ```
   drwx------ 2 vagrant vagrant 4096 Nov 14 21:53 .
   drwx------ 4 vagrant vagrant 4096 Nov 15 01:40 ..
   -rw-r--r-- 1 vagrant vagrant 1557 Nov 15 03:47 authorized_keys
   ```
5. I even tried doing a chmod 700 authorized_keys and it did not work
6. I can confirm that the public key from Mac has been successfully copied to the authorized_keys on Ubuntu
7. This is the ssh output

   ```
   ssh vagrant@192.168.58.1 -vvv
   OpenSSH_6.9p1, LibreSSL 2.1.8
   debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
   debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
   debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
   debug1: Connecting to 192.168.58.1 [192.168.58.1] port 22.
   debug1: Connection established.
   debug1: identity file /Users/JK/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
   debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
   debug1: identity file /Users/JK/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
   debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
   debug1: identity file /Users/JK/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
   debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
   debug1: identity file /Users/JK/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
   debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
   debug1: identity file /Users/JK/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
   debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
   debug1: identity file /Users/JK/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
   debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
   debug1: identity file /Users/JK/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
   debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
   debug1: identity file /Users/JK/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
   debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
   debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.9
   debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.9
   debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.9 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
   debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
   debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.58.1:22 as 'vagrant'
   debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/JK/.ssh/known_hosts"
   debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /Users/JK/.ssh/known_hosts:1
   debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 192.168.58.1
   debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
   debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
   debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1,hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1,hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
   debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
   debug1: kex: server->client chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
   debug1: kex: client->server chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
   debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
   debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:Yjfn7E49YWk/EE22fYrJvLusCs+VbvDDzppSUCHDBt8
   debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/JK/.ssh/known_hosts"
   debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /Users/JK/.ssh/known_hosts:1
   debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 192.168.58.1
   debug1: Host '192.168.58.1' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
   debug1: Found key in /Users/JK/.ssh/known_hosts:1
   debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
   debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
   debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
   debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
   debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
   debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
   debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
   debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
   debug2: key: /Users/JK/.ssh/id_rsa (0x7f8241e15210),
   debug2: key: /Users/JK/.ssh/id_dsa (0x0),
   debug2: key: /Users/JK/.ssh/id_ecdsa (0x0),
   debug2: key: /Users/JK/.ssh/id_ed25519 (0x0),
   debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
   debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,keyboard-interactive
   debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
   debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
   debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
   debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
   debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
   debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/JK/.ssh/id_rsa
   debug3: send_pubkey_test
   debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
   debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
   debug1: Trying private key: /Users/JK/.ssh/id_dsa
   debug3: no such identity: /Users/JK/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
   debug1: Trying private key: /Users/JK/.ssh/id_ecdsa
   debug3: no such identity: /Users/JK/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
   debug1: Trying private key: /Users/JK/.ssh/id_ed25519
   debug3: no such identity: /Users/JK/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
   debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
   debug3: authmethod_lookup keyboard-interactive
   debug3: remaining preferred: password
   debug3: authmethod_is_enabled keyboard-interactive
   debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
   debug2: userauth_kbdint
   debug2: we sent a keyboard-interactive packet, wait for reply
   debug2: input_userauth_info_req
   debug2: input_userauth_info_req: num_prompts 1
   Password:
   debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
   debug2: userauth_kbdint
   debug2: we sent a keyboard-interactive packet, wait for reply
   debug2: input_userauth_info_req
   debug2: input_userauth_info_req: num_prompts 1
   Password:
   debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
   debug2: userauth_kbdint
   debug2: we sent a keyboard-interactive packet, wait for reply
   debug2: input_userauth_info_req
   debug2: input_userauth_info_req: num_prompts 1
   Password:
   debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
   debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
   debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
   Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

According to your post, you installed your public key in /.ssh/authorized_keys and you are connecting as user "vagrant", this means that you have to install your public key in /home/vagrant/.ssh/authorized_keys instead

Comment: Hi there, Thanks for getting back to me. By /.ssh/authorized_keys, I mean /home/vagrant/.ssh/authorized_keys only. i.e they both denote the same. Any other ideas?

Comment: what are the perms of /home/vagrant/.ssh ? `ls -ld /home/vagrant/.ssh`  Also have a look at /var/log/syslog or /var/log/messages or /var/log/secure on the destination host, you may have interesting stuff about sshd deny reason.